# Limit number post per taxonomy term name

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to make some limitation in pager and display aritcles per term. I think that i can with Views and  but i would like to do with some simple preprocess or hooks (if it can). Taxonomy display modules do limitation per vocabulary. I don't know where to start.

e.g.
I have one vocabulary (locations) with different terms (lakes, mountains, buildings)
and I have about 20 articles in lakes, but i have 300 in buildings so i want to improve UI.
I want to limit pager 10 per lakes and 50 per builidngs. And terms must stay in same Vocab.

How to do it 
thanks

Comment: anyone can help?